# Burninate request [python3]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, tags

I would like to request burnination of [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) as it completely describes in its wiki:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! You want [python-3.x] instead.

This is a useless synonym and request for it to removed, as it has no tagged questions and I think removing this would give new users confusion-free choosing better tag to be used.

Comment: It only has one question.  Retag that, and the tag will eventually die.

Comment: it has no tag a while ago. it just posted as of now clearly another confused user.

Comment: Ah, right.  That question was asked only a few minutes ago, then it was retagged just now.

Comment: so any burnination there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was one question with [python3](/questions/tagged/python3). I retagged it to [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), so the tag should self-immolate in the automated cleanup.

[image]

Comment: or self destruct? :)

Comment: @AsshO.Le "Self-immolate" has a linguistic connection to "burninate", and sounds cooler.

Comment: This tag is soon to be burninated? how bout that? it would be burninated after the cleanup you say :) hahah

Comment: Oh don't worry, it'll be back.  Someone recreates it about once a week, just like `server` and `access`.